# Can't find NHibernate mapping file: noob question

Tags: .net, nhibernate

Struggling with NHibernate and would appreciate any help. I've got a table called 'orders' and a class called 'Order'. I'm using MVC3, and this is my exception

NHibernate.MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document: Orders.hbm.xml ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\Orders.hbm.xml'.

(this is when I try to start the app). I'm guessing it's a) a problem with the mapping file itself and therefore not copying it to the IIS deployment folder, or I need to define it as some sort of 'embedde resorce' (which it is). Bit new to this...

My mapping file is in 'Mappings/Orders.hbm.xml' and looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="Munch"
                   namespace="Munch.Models">

  <class name="Order" table="orders">
    <id name="id">
      <generator class="int32" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

If anyone can tell me what's wrong I will be really grateful (or even if you can tell me how to get some more info as to how to get more detail on the error)

Thanks

PS I'm from Java/Spring/JPA land but trying to put together a decent stack for my team. I'm hoping these .NET versions translate well to work with MVC3 in .NET land but if anyone wants to recommend better technologies I'm all ears!

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to embed hbm file as resource into your assembly. In Visual Studio Solution Explorer:

Right click on Order.hbm.xml -> Properties -> Set Build Action = EmbeddedResource. And let NHibernate know about the location of hbm file by calling `AddAssembly`:

```
var config = new Configuration();
...
config.AddAssembly("AssemblyThatContainsOrders");

ISessionFactory sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
```

See [this](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx) for details. And the generator mapping should look like this:

```
<id name="id" column="Id" type="Int32">
    <generator class="native" />
</id>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried what you suggested last thing yesterday and it did get me further (it's complaining about the dialect, so I guess my main mapping is incorrect too somehow). Many thanks.

Comment: See last update. Also you should open another question if you are experiencing different problem.

Comment: Yep, cheers. Was doing it last thing last night so today (at work) I followed up on your advice and realised what I was doing wrong (i.e. what you mention in your update). Appreciate the help, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: BTW, I would be very interested to hear your opinion on using NHibernate (and Spring.NET if you use that) together with ASP/MVC3. My experience with the Java version is that they are an excellent stack to use. I'm just getting into the .NET side of things so hoping they also add a lot of benefits over the out-of-the-box MS technologies.

Comment: NHibernate is definitely stable, mature and pleasant to work with. Especially in DDD scenario, that seems to cause much pain with EF (based on questions asked on Stackoverflow).

Answer (score 0):

Your generator declaration is wrong. See section 5.1.4 in [the documentation](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-5-basic-o-r-mapping#5%282E%291%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Mapping_declaration) for valid values for the generator class attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean I think. I'll have a good look at it when I get chance and fix it. Cheers.